# How do I get the correct color for Minecraft swamp grass?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, color

I've got the texture and the material and the UV mapping down for the grass, but I can't seem to be getting the color down. It keeps getting too light, not showing enough green, too tan, or not 'lush' enough for swamp grass.[image]

I've tried taking the swamp grass hexadecimal(#4c763c) from here (refer to item 1 in the link below) then getting RGB percentages from here (refer to item 2 in the link below) and putting them into the textures property like this (R: 1.298, G: 1.463, B: 1.235), but the result is disappointing: (refer to item 3 in the link below)

I have also tried putting the RGB values into color balance in gimp: (refer to item 4 in the link below)

The original Minecraft texture: (refer to Item 5 in the link below)

target color: (refer to item 6 in the link below)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xbP10JUztmZoTq74KTY-mh4eX07V6YpAMq_Rd6fN6BE/edit?usp=sharing (I can't have more than 2 links because i don't yet have 10 rep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly it should look, but you can set the hexadecimal value (#4c763c) to the diffuse color and the intensity to 1, then change the blending mode of the texture to Multiply.

[image: grass_top]

You can do it in GIMP by adding a new layer, fill it with that color and change the mode to multiply.

Comment: Thank you, I did find a different solution by going into gimp and creating a semi-transparent green texture on top of it, but this one achieves much better results

Answer (score 0):

Swamp has the temperature 0.8 and a rainfall/humidity of 0.9. Go to your resource pack and pick the color at the corresponding place (I'll add a link and a picture to how to do it later)

To color the grass, multiply the black-white-texture with your color. That's it.

Comment: That's what I showed in the images I tried to multiply the colors